# How to know what we are receiving from Internet

Tags: networking, internet, security

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with additional backports PPA (to get LTS).

But... I guess it is valid to any Ubuntu release.

Is there some GUI and/or Terminal app to know what kind of data some IP address is sending to our PCs?

I'm not talking about some "not human" binary, hexadecimal or decimal number series, no.

I'm talking about some app that shows us, let's say: "This IP is asking for your physical IP". In other words... Some useful "Human" language data.

Is there something like that? Where?

Of course, it should be useful some way to let or deny the traffic request.

Comment: The packets you send *already* include your IP address so the server at the other end knows where to respond. Any machine that is "querying" to learn your IP address already knows it before you would receive a prompt. However, knowing your IP address won't get most intruders very far - a desktop install of Ubuntu has no exploitable listening ports for the intruder to connect to.  If you install a service that binds to a port and listens, read the documentation carefully to learn how to use it safely.

Comment: You could install and run `wireshark` to see all your packets, or any of the network traffic tools listed by `apt-cache search 'tcpdump|wireshark'`.  You'll be surprised by how much "ovehead" traffic goes on.